# Angular - Need help in File replacements in Angular.json with Assets (IMAGES)

Tags: angular, image

```
"dev": {
              "index": "src/index_dev.html",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/assets/images/logos/logo.png",
                  "with": "src/assets/images/logos/logo_dev.png"
                },
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },

in older versions of angular, changing logos for different environments was easy, but now this code is not working, just this has issue
{    
"replace": "src/assets/images/logos/logo.png",    
"with": "src/assets/images/logos/logo_dev.png"   
 }
```

need help

I need to use two different logos for two different environments using FILE REPLACEMENT in Angular.json.

Comment: I did read something about that kind of issue, where you need to explicitly declare the assets you want to replace. https://dev.to/remshams/replacing-configuration-files-in-angular-builds-based-on-build-targets-28jm What version are you running by the way ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in environments -> environment.ts for now as a new version of Angular is not supporting that in FILE REPLACEMENT.
By Configuring this, I can control each environment and they will have their own Variables (Logos and Images) with minimal changes in Code.

```
export const environment = {
  mainLogo: "assets/images/logos/logoXYZ.png",
  production: true,
  firebase: {
     xyz, xyz
  },
   verticalApiEndpoint: xyz xyz 
};
```